# Как получить имя и фамилию пользователя VK на русском языке?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Метод API users.get() почему-то возвращает имя и фамилию транслитом.

В то же время, widget авторизации прекрасно получает и возвращает имя-фамилию кириллицей. Но я не хочу его использовать.

**Upd.** Проблема была вызвана георасположением моего сервера в штатах, которому vk предпочел, видимо, отвечать по-английски.

**Решение** Добавлять curl-запросам к api HTTP заголовок `Accept-Language: ru`:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language: ru,en-us'));
```

Comment: А у меня все замечательно кириллицей отображается в users.get.  
Если вы работаете через JS или что-то подобное, могу предположить, что "умный" ВКонтактовский скрипт использует вашу текущую локаль или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Сервер "звонит", PHP / cURL. Странно. Посмотрите мой id=755074, будет ли у вас кириллица там, где у меня "Seryoga"?

Comment: @sergiks я использую desktop API, так что хз (но вот пруф http://db.tt/riTrozE4).  
Копайте в сторону локали.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

теперь есть параметр **lang**

https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

Передача параметров в API
Параметры могут передаваться как методом GET, так и POST. Если вы будете передавать большие данные (больше 2 килобайт), то следует использовать метод POST.

Каждый метод имеет собственный набор поддерживаемых параметров, однако существуют параметры, которые принимают все методы:

lang — определяет язык, на котором будут возвращаться различные данные, например названия стран и городов. Также если указан не русский, украинский и белорусский язык, то кириллические имена будут автоматически транслированы в латиницу. ru - Русский, ua - Украинский, be - Белорусский, en- Английский, es - Испанский, fi - Финский, de - Немецкий, it - Итальянский. Также поддерживается числовой идентификатор языка, возвращаемый методом account.getInfo.

Comment: С 2012-го много воды утекло : )

Comment: утекло, а таки работает

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался. Мой сервер физически находится в штатах, видимо, поэтому vk api решил выпендриться и заговорить по-английски.
Вылечил добавлением HTTP заголовка `Accept-Language: ru` всем curl запросам:
`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language: ru,en-us'));`